# Typescript implicit types (not implicit any)

Tags: typescript, types, implicit-typing

In a Typescript project I worked on that I don't have access to anymore, I remember seeming to be able to do the following:

```js
const fn = string => console.log(string)
```

Being new to Typescript, it seemed to be the equivalent of writing this:

```
const fn = (string:string) => console.log(string)
```

Basically, in my mind, if I named a variable in a function after a native type, it would seem to implicitly be typed as that type, not as `any`.

I was very new to Typescript at the time though so it's totally possible something else was really going on and I was just misinterpreting the situation.

Now that I am trying to set up my own typescript project, I would like to configure it to allow that functionality again. I'm not sure how to though or if what I'm thinking of is even a real Typescript feature.

Is this a real feature in Typescript?

If it is, how do I configure Typescript to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically, in my mind, if I named a variable in a function after a native type, it would seem to implicitly be typed as that type, not as `any`.

This is entirely wrong. Typescript does not have such a feature. If you do not mention a type, Typescript will simply consider it as `any`. This is the same thing happening in the code below.

```
const fn = string => console.log(string)
```

`string` variable is of `any` type. If you have a modern IDE it would show you the same thing if you hover over it.

[image]

To give it a type, you have to specifically mention a type, just like in the latter code you added.

```
const fn = (string:string) => console.log(string)
```

[image]

> Is this a real feature in Typescript?
>
> If it is, how do I configure Typescript to do this?

It is not and thus you can't configure it to work that way normally.

Answer (score 1):

The closest feature to what you're describing is called **Contextual Typing** or **Type Inference**. You can look it up in [TypeScript's documentation for more details](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html).

As for the example you have given, the standard (node) definition of `console.log` is expecting `message` param to by of `any` type. That's why in this case your `string` parameter infers to `any` type.

```js
// src: node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts

interface Console {

    // ...

    /**
     * Prints to `stdout` with newline
     */
     log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I wish I had access to the old project I worked on that made me think Typescript had this feature. Your answer sounds the closest to what was really going on but I want to do a bit of testing before I accept this as the answer.

Comment: I did a bit of testing and contextual typing doesn't really seem to work when the `noImplicitAny` option is enabled. Or at least VS Code doesn't seem to accept it as a thing. I even pasted the code directly from the docs to be sure.